# How to get a file from KnownFolder.DocumentsLibrary

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, uwp

I need some help on File and Folders operations.

I need to retrieve a file in subfolder in a main Folder in the Document Library.

Let say, I create the following folder and subfolder in Documents Folder:

1. I create a main Folder with name : MyWorkShop
2. In the Main Folder : MyWorkShop , I create a SubFolder in it and name it : 2016-08-10
3. in the Subfolder there is a file myfile.txt

Is Document Library Folder refer to the Documents Folder in C-drive?

How to I retrieve the file in the Subfolder ?

Below is my current code, how to start from here?

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;

StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("myfile.txt");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary` references normally to `%USERPROFILE%\Documents` (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.storage.knownfolders.documentslibrary)).

You have to load each subfolder before being able to access the file.

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
StorageFolder mainFolder = await storageFolder.GetFolderAsync("MyWorkShop");
StorageFolder subFolder = await mainFolder.GetFolderAsync("2016-08-10");
StorageFile sampleFile = await subFolder.GetFileAsync("myfile.txt");
```